# how to fix 'org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0' error

Tags: java, spring

I got an error

```
org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.nullableSingleResult(DataAccessUtils.java:97)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:236)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:244)
    at com.regularbbs.bbs.dao.UserDao.findUserByIdAndPw(UserDao.java:38)
    at com.regularbbs.bbs.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.login(UserServiceImpl.java:20)
```

I think it doesn't take my parameter to MySQL database. When I tested, I found my parameters were passed to DAO file. But it goes right into catch. When I printed out the map in `findUserByIdAndPw` method in DAO file, it printed the parameters in map well.

I think `jdbc.queryForObject(GET_USER, map, rowMapper);` is wrong, but I have no clue, please help me.

```
package com.regularbbs.bbs.dao;

public class UserSqls {
    public static final String GET_USER = "SELECT * from user WHERE userId=':userId' AND password=':password'";
}
'''
```

Jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/css/main.css' />" >
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:include page="header.jsp" flush="false"></jsp:include>
    <c:if test="${sessionScope.login ==null }">
        <form name="login">
            <section id="loginSection">
                아이디 : <input type="text" id="userId" placeholder="아이디">
                패스워드 : <input type="password" id="userPwd" placeholder="패스워드">
                <button type="button" id="btnLogin">로그인</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="getSignUpPage()">회원가입</button>
            </section>
        </form>
    </c:if>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getSignUpPage() {
        location.href="signUp";
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnLogin").click(function() {

            var userId = $("#userId").val();
            var userPwd = $("#userPwd").val();
            var allData = JSON.stringify({"userId": userId, "password": userPwd});
            if(userId == "") {
                $("#userId").focus();
                return;
            }
            if(userPwd == "") {
                $("#userPwd").focus();
                return;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "member/login",
                data: allData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log("error : ", e);
                }
            })
        })
    });
</script>
</html>
```

UserDao class:

```
package com.regularbbs.bbs.dao;

import static com.regularbbs.bbs.dao.UserSqls.GET_USER;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.regularbbs.bbs.dto.User;

@Repository
public class UserDao {

    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbc;

    private RowMapper<User> rowMapper = BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(User.class);

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbc = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public User findUserByIdAndPw(String id, String pw) {
        try {
            System.out.println(id +":"+ pw);
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("userId", id);
            map.put("password", pw);
            System.out.println(map);
            return jdbc.queryForObject(GET_USER, map, rowMapper);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Service:

```
package com.regularbbs.bbs.service;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.regularbbs.bbs.dto.User;

public interface UserService {
    public User login(String userId, String password) throws Exception;
}



package com.regularbbs.bbs.service.impl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.regularbbs.bbs.dao.UserDao;
import com.regularbbs.bbs.dto.User;
import com.regularbbs.bbs.service.UserService;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User login(String userId, String password) throws Exception{
        return userDao.findUserByIdAndPw(userId, password);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
package com.regularbbs.bbs.controller;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.regularbbs.bbs.dto.User;
import com.regularbbs.bbs.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/member/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String loginPost(@RequestBody Map<String, String> data
            , Model model, HttpSession session) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(data.get("userId") + ": " + data.get("password"));
        User loginUser = userService.login(data.get("userId"), data.get("password"));
        if(loginUser!=null) {
            session.setAttribute("login", loginUser);
            return "redirect:/";
        }else {
            return "redirect:/";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`JDBCTemplate` 's `queryForObject` is supposed to return a single unique record. Otherwise , it will throw :

- `IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException` if the SQL return more than 1
  record
- `EmptyResultDataAccessException` if the SQL return no record

Normally you can catch this exception and convert it to some exception message that is meaningful to your application. Re-throw the exception back to controller such that Spring MVC can handle this exception . For example :

```
public User findUserByIdAndPw(String id, String pw) {
    try {
        System.out.println(id +":"+ pw);
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("userId", id);
        map.put("password", pw);
        System.out.println(map);
        return jdbc.queryForObject(GET_USER, map, rowMapper);
    }catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("User ID does not exist");
    }catch(IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("More than one users with the same Id .......");
    }
}
```